# Проектирование БД SQL с множественным полем

Tags: sql, база-данных, mysqli

Есть таблица Users, в которой хранится "логин", "пароль", и "id интересных страниц"(список сообществ)

Вопрос в том, что "id интересных страниц" может включать в себя много id'шников.

Как их хранить или как еще можно сделать архитектуру?

Comment: Сделать другую таблицу в которой будет идентификатор юзера в одном поле, и айдишник страницы в другом.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте таблицу что-то типа FavoritePage (id, UserID, PageID), со связью один ко многим, получите правильное хранение. Не хотите новую таблицу, городите костыли с разделителем.